# Excel OFFSET function error when using TREND in reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula, offset, named-ranges, trend

Consider an Excel sheet with the following values:

```
   A   B
 --------
1| 1   5
2| 2   8
3| 3  11
```

Entering the array formula `=TREND(B1:B3,A1:A3,A1:A3)` in cells C1:C3 returns `{5;8;11}`, as expected.  Entering `=OFFSET(C1:C3,1,0)` returns `{8;11;0}`, also as expected.

However, if I try entering `=ROWS(OFFSET(TREND(B1:B3,A1:A3,A1:A3),1,0))`, I get the message, "The formula you typed contains an error".  I can't do anything to get it to accept the formula.

Next I created the named ranges "TrendRange" and "TrendFormula" with the formulae `=Sheet1!$C$1:$C$3` and `=TREND(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$3,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$3,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$3)`, respectively.

Again, `=OFFSET(TrendRange,1,0)` gives the correct result but `=OFFSET(TrendFormula,1,0)` does not (it results in `#VALUE!`).

There is a simple test that seems to always identify when OFFSET will have this issue.  If `=CELL("address", xxx)` or `=AREAS(xxx)` result in `#VALUE!`, then the xxx section can't be used in OFFSET.

Is there any way around this?  I've tried using LINEST and SLOPE/INTERCEPT instead of TREND, but I get the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OFFSET requires a **reference** (a cell or a range as the first argument), it won't accept an array, so because a formula like

`=TREND(B1:B3,A1:A3,A1:A3)`

always returns an array, you can't use it as the first argument of OFFSET. Is this related to your previous question?

Comment: Ok, thanks again Barry.  I was hoping to find a trick to get around this limitation, but apparently there's not (other than VBA).  Yes, it is related to [my other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13709313/excel-formula-to-pad-array).